# ul list with svg and tspan

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to use text wrapping in a text/tspan svg element.  I'm essentially try to take the code such as this:  (ignore the text wrapping part of it for right now)

```
<svg>
    <g>
        <text>
             Date: date here
            <tspan>this is a list item</tspan>
            <tspan>this is another list item</tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I'm trying to make it like an unordered HTML list:

```
Date: date here
<ul>
    <li>this is a list item</li>
    <li>this is another list item</li>
</ul>
```

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In SVG, you need to manually position each line of text.

You could layout the text using a separate `<text>` element for each line. For example...

```
<svg>
    <g>
        <text x="0em" y="1em">Date: date here</text>
        <circle cx="1.75em" cy="2.75em" r="2px"/>
        <text x="2.5em" y="3em">this is a list item</text>
        <circle cx="1.75em" cy="3.75em" r="2px"/>
        <text x="2.5em" y="4em">this is another list item</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Or you could layout the text using a single `<text>` with a separate `<tspan>` element for each line break. For example...

```
<svg>
    <g>
        <circle cx="1.75em" cy="2.75em" r="2px"/>
        <circle cx="1.75em" cy="3.75em" r="2px"/>
        <text x="0em" y="1em">
            Date: date here
            <tspan x="2.5em" dy="2em">this is a list item</tspan>
            <tspan x="2.5em" dy="1em">this is another list item</tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

**Edit:** Added `<circle>` elements for the dots before each list item.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm sorry, I wasn't clear.  Most of all, I was wondering how to do the icon for the dot of an unordered list.  Thank you for the dx dy positioning, yet, I think I have that already.

Comment: You can use a small filled circle element for the dots before each list item.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought about that too, but I guess the text wrapping might interfere with that a bit.  I see how you have the circles drawn outside the <text> element.  THough, I am doing this through JavaScript/jQuery, and I will have to figure out about doing calculations for the circle.setAttribute('cx', '1.75em'), etc.  Thank you, I won't mark this as an answer yet, but I'll do it once I get this to work.